# Need assistance figuring out why this slider wont flip to the background in ie9/10

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transforms

This question is related to 3d transform.

For some weird reason it flips to the other side but doesnt show the content just the opposite of the front frame.

Any ideas?

I made a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dvmad/qqda2cuh/1/

Code(HTNL):

```
<section class="cardcontainer">
<div id="kard">
<figure class="front">Front Text</figure>
<figure class="back">This is a example of the back text. This is a example of the back text.</figure>
</div>
</section>
```

Code(CSS):

```
.cardcontainer {
  /*
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  */
  width: 380px;
  height: 230px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  /*
  border: 1px solid #CCC;     
 -webkit-perspective: 800px;
     -moz-perspective: 800px;
       -o-perspective: 800px;
          perspective: 800px;
          */
}
@media screen  and (min-width:1000px)
{
    .cardcontainer {

  width: 380px;
  height: 230px;
  position:static;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
    }
}



#kard {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
          transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#kard:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
     -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );

       -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
          transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

#kard figure {
    display: block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
line-height: 50px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 25px;
position: absolute;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding-top:25%;

}

#kard .front {
      background-color:#76c430;
}

#kard .back {
  background-color:#3292b1;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height:20px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
     -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
       -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
          transform: rotateY( 180deg );
          padding-left:10px;
          padding-right:10px;

}
/*for cell phone sizes*/
@media screen and (max-width:500px){
    #kard .back {
          padding-left:20px;
          padding-right:20px;
    }
}
#kard .back span{
    max-width:50%;
}
```

Any ideas why?

I don't know the 3d transform stuff so well so im at a a loss.

Was able to grab a example to make this but it doesnt work in ie9/10 as previously said.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 1):

IE9 doesn't support transitions and backface-visibility so that's game over.

IE10 doesn't support backface-visibility so that's game over too.

So what to do?

You can try writing your own javascript solution with the css filter property and setInterval animations, or just use some jquery flip plugin with a conditional tag.

Comment: I dont believe thats true. how come it works here

[link]https://www.meclabs.com/training/marketing-summit/marketingsherpa-summit-2016/experience

Comment: @Dave That website probably uses tricks like the answer below and jquery animations as fallback. Just check http://caniuse.com yourself...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is give the front div a higher `z-index` than the back div, and when `#kard` is rotated switch the `z-index`s of the front and back div. Set the `transition-delay` of the front and back div to a certain value in order for the `z-index` transition to be done when the container is rotating at 90 degrees:

```
#kard {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
          transition: transform 1s;

}    
#kard:hover {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );

           -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
              transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    }    



#kard .front {
      background-color:#76c430;
      z-index: 1;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      transition-delay: 0.3s;
      position: absolute;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
#kard:hover .front{
  z-index: 0;
}
#kard:hover .back{
  z-index: 1;
}
    #kard .back {
      background-color:#3292b1;
      font-size: 15px;
      line-height:20px;
      -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
              transform: rotateY( 180deg );
              padding-left:10px;
              padding-right:10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        z-index: 0;
              position: absolue;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        transition-delay: 0.3s;
    }
```

Comment: this didnt work it just dissapears when it flips around

Comment: As a relatively new SO user, I'd like to give you some feedback to help your contributions be more useful: 1. Code-only answers are not useful.  Explain what you've done - either in comments within the code, or in the answer.  2. Comments like "Try this" are also not helpful.  It suggests you haven't tried it yourself, so you don't know if it works.  3. When possible, a jsFiddle or CodePen is most useful, **especially in cases like this** where the OP included a fiddle.  Edit their fiddle and use that to prove your solution works.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm new at this :)

Comment: Nice idea about using the z-index and transition-delay. This is a great fallback for IE10, on IE9 there is sadly no transition property so that would require using js with setInterval or jQuery animate.

Comment: Mahmoud thanks for the idea it didnt work i updated the fiddle. 

Now when i mouse over it flips around the same that was the bug in IE version.

Comment: Mahmoud this still fails in IE, it used to work in IE11 now fails in IE11.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help much